# HUE clears Table Name filter after create/drop table execution

Tags: hadoop, hue

I'm running HUE 4 on Impala (HADOOP)

Here's my steps:

1. Go to the Editor window
2. In Table Name Filter (left panel) type some text (e.g. "test", "tmp")
3. See that this filter applied and in tables list shows only relevant tables
4. Perform "create table" or "drop table" operation
5. See that left panel refreshes and Table Name filter clears - that's *inconvenient*.

It there any way to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to create an improvement issue on: https://github.com/cloudera/hue/issues

Comment: Romain, thanks for suggestion. If there will be no solution here, then will do.